# Bootstrap 5 mobile Dropdown not sliding while clicking

Tags: html, css, frontend, navbar, bootstrap-5

### Few things to know before starting:-

1. I'm using **Django** (python)
2. I'm using **Bootstrap**
3. And Obviously I'm using **html** and **css**

### What I did (in order, when before I got an error):

1. I copied the **navbar** template from the [bootstrap navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#supported-content)
2. I linked my own **custom css and js file** from the static directory of django in the following order below:-

#### Javascript Files

(Copied from Bootstrap, so don't mind the comments) :)

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="{% static '/js/script.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

#### Css Files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css'%}" />
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

---

#### Code in main html file

```
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css'%}" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>{%block title%} {%endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img
            src="{% static '/img/Socklet-logos.jpeg' %}"
            alt="error in loading static files, may encounter bad design"
            id="brand-logo"
            class="float-start"
          />
          <h1 id="brand">{%block brand%}{%endblock%}</h1></a
        >
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div
          class="collapse navbar-collapse"
          id="navbarSupportedContent navbar"
        >
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" id="navigation-bar">
            <li class="nav-item" id="nav">
              <a
                class="nav-link active"
                aria-current="page"
                href="#"
                id="nav-link"
              >
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  class="bi bi-house-door"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                  class="nav-icon"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-4h2v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H14a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146zM2.5 14V7.707l5.5-5.5 5.5 5.5V14H10v-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v4H2.5z"
                  />
                </svg>
                Home</a
              >
            </li>
            <hr style="color: white" />
            <li class="nav-item" id="nav">
              <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link" href="#">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  class="bi bi-kanban-fill"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                  class="nav-icon"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M2.5 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h11a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-11zm5 2h1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1zm-5 1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v7a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3zm9-1h1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1z"
                  />
                </svg>
                Projects</a
              >
            </li>
            <hr style="color: white" />
            <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="nav">
              <a
                class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                id="navbarDropdown"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
                id="nav-link"
              >
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  class="bi bi-three-dots"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                  class="nav-icon"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M3 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3z"
                  />
                </svg>

                More
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Book Club</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Employees</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="d-flex">
            <a href="{{login_logout_link}}">
              <button
                class="btn btn-outline-success"
                name="login"
                id="login-btn"
              >
                {{login_logout}}
              </button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="{% static '/js/script.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

---

#### Code in custom Css file

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-icon {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 40px;
    max-width: 140px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-icon {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 125px;
  }
}

#nav {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#nav:hover {
  background-color: black;
  text-shadow: 500px;
}

#login-button {
  align-items: right;
}

#brand:hover {
  color: black;
}

#login-btn {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100px;
}

#nav-link {
  padding: 10px;
}

svg {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  #brand {
    padding-right: 250px;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  #brand-logo {
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 90px;
  }
}

#brand-logo {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 55px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#navigation-bar {
  align-items: center;
}
```

But here's the final output with a gif in which I'm **clicking the dropdown but it doesn't slide**:-

[image: I'm clicking the dropdown but it doesn't slide down]

Comment: Please tell me if you want to know something down here, I'll edit the post and add the details you want

Comment: The question is finally solved by @LuizdeLimaSouza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id on:

```
    <div
      class="collapse navbar-collapse"
      id="navbarSupportedContent navbar"
    >
```

Must have the same value as `data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"`. That's how the button and the dropdown `<div>` are linked.

Try changing it to `id="navbarSupportedContent"`

Comment: It didn't work for me.
And moreover, there is no jquery in bootstrap 5, bootstrap 5 has removed jquery. The second thing also didn't work for me. :(

Comment: I forgot something. It's also necessary to remove "-bs" from data-bs-target too. And you're right about the jQuery removal in bootstrap, but, some bootstrap features like dropdowns and modals aren't working, at least for me, without jQuery even though most animations works just fine. Try removing "-bs" and adding jQuery and tell me how it went :)

Comment: Ok. Forget everything I said before, I've tested your html here and now it's working in my PC. The problem was your <div> id, it should be id="navbarSupportedContent" instead of id="navbarSupportedContent navbar". Let me know how it went :)